# Modify the Additional CSS section (adding a disclaimer)

Tags: theme-development, customization, css, theme-customizer

I was trying to dig into this deeper, but I couldn't find any useful ways/hooks to add a little disclaimer above the Additional CSS code editor in the Wordpress Customizer. If anyone has a starting point of how i can add something simple like that, it would be greatly appreciated.

The section I am talking about is `wp-admin > Appearance > Customize > Additonal CSS`

We basically want to add a disclaimer to our clients about using that section, and I wanted to do it the Wordpress way, and not hack anything using jQuery (to add it) or in core.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. I was able to show it by default using:

```
<?php
add_action('customize_controls_print_styles', function()  {
?>
    <style id="custom-css">
        #sub-accordion-section-custom_css .description {
            display: block !important;
        }
    </style>
<?php
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You will need the [`get_section`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/get_section) method of the `$wp_customizer class`. Like this:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'wpse261932_change_css_title', 15 );

function wpse261932_change_css_title () {
  global $wp_customize;
  $wp_customize->get_section('custom_css')->title = __('Additional CSS. Be careful!', 'textdomain');
  }
```

For some reason the description has `display:none` on it in this panel, even though that would be a more logical place to show your disclaimer.

Comment: Ah... Good call @cjbj. The description would definitely be better, and from the looks of it, you can show the description by clicking on the question mark button, and it will drop down. Now I wonder if I could hook into the javascript that controls that whole feature, and after some even is triggered, trigger a click on the question mark to drop it down. Or, maybe i could do something with CSS.

Comment: You could queue a css file for the customizer to have the description shown by default